# Filter events by calendar id with Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Python library, but it seems it's still on the 2 version of the API. I can't find it in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_python) about filtering events with the calendar id or a property in the event itself which is a reference to which calendar it belongs to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So why aren't you using the v3 API?

Comment: Wanted to use the Python library provided by Google. I'm already using the Contacts API with the library (which already uses the latest version), and a bit constrained with time to write my own wrapper.

Comment: But there is a Python library for the version 3 API, of course. I've been happily using it for a year.

Comment: Ohh. I've been using the [gdata](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) library for Contacts, and wanted to use the same for Calendar. You're using the [google-api-python-client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) right? Gonna check it out. Thanks.